# How to get keywords of ios app programmatically?

Tags: ios

There are a lot of services (for example appstorerankings.net) who shows apps keywords.
How they do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the [Apple Search (Lookup) API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) ;).